# Расчёт средней заработной платы с помощью стримов

Tags: java

Задача: расчёт средней заработной платы отделов с помощью стримов

```
public class Task implements AutoCloseable {

    public static List<Double> avgEmp = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Department> departments = new HashMap<>();

        String path = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : null;

        assert path != null;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "CP1251")); br) {
            String line; // Как мне объявить line в while
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (check(line)) {
                    String[] strings = line.split("/");
                    Employee emp = new Employee(strings[0], new Double(strings[1]));
                    if (!departments.containsKey(strings[2])) {
                        departments.put(strings[2], new Department(strings[2]));
                    }
                    departments.get(strings[2]).addEmployee(emp);
                    System.out.println(strings[0] + " " + strings[1] + " " + strings[2] + " - корректна, обрабатываем");
                }
            }
            systemMessage(0);
            avg(departments);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Файл не был найден, проверьте путь");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Исправьте путь к файлу, выходите за массив");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("Вы забыли прописать путь к файлу");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Читаемый файл закрыт");
        }
    }

    public static boolean check(String line) {
        String regex = "[А-Яа-яЁёA-Za-z\\s]+";
        if (!(line = line.trim()).isEmpty()) {
            String[] strings = line.split("/");
            if (strings.length < 3) {
                System.out.println(line + " - неверный формат строки, ожидаем ФИО/10000.12/Департамент");
                return false;
            }
            if (!(strings[0].matches(regex) && strings[2].matches(regex))) {
                System.out.println(line + " - неверный формат ввода, нужно: Буквы/Цифры/Буквы");
                return false;
            }
            if (!strings[1].matches("\\d{5}(\\.\\d{1,2})?")) {
                System.out.println(line + " - некорректный ввод цифр, знаков. Зарплата не может быть отрицательной и иметь меньше 5 знаков");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    public static void avg(Map<String, Department> departments) {
        for (Department dep : departments.values()) {
            Double avg = dep.salaryAvg();
            avgEmp.add(avg);
            System.out.println("Средняя заработная плата отдела " + dep.getName   () + ": " + avg);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слишком сложная реализация.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@lombok.Data
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{
    
    private final String name;    
    private final Double salary;    
    private final String departmentName;
    
    public static Map<String, Queue<Employee>> fromFile(String fileName, String separator) throws IOException {
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            return stream
                    .map(line -> line.split(separator))                    
                    .map(args->Employee.of(args))
                    .filter(employee->employee!=null)
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartmentName, HashMap::new, 
                            Collectors.toCollection(PriorityQueue::new)));
        }
    }
    
    private static Employee of(String[] args) {
        try {
            return new Employee(args[0].trim(), Double.valueOf(args[1].trim()), args[2].trim());
        } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee employee) {
        return this.salary.compareTo(employee.salary);
    }
    
}

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.springframework.data.util.Pair;

public class Task {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        Map<String, Queue<Employee>> employes = Employee.fromFile("1.txt", "/");
        
        Map<String, Double> salaryAvg = 
                employes.entrySet().stream()
                        .map(e->Pair.of(e.getKey(), e.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(Employee::getSalary).average().getAsDouble()))
                        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Pair::getSecond))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getFirst, Pair::getSecond, (o1, o2) -> o1, LinkedHashMap::new));
        
        System.out.println(salaryAvg);
        
        //todo
        
    }

}
```

Сделайте класс сотрудников немного "умнее". Пусть он сам себя парсит.
Тогда из класса Task просто вызывайте метод класса сотрудников для того, чтобы преобразовать текстовый файл в коллекцию типа Map, при этом в аргументах передается имя файла и разделитель, но поскольку используется split разделителем может быть и регулярка для более сложных случаев.

Из метода вы получите практически такую же Map, только ее значение будет типизировано очередью с приоритетом, а не листом. Для этого типа коллекции можно задать компаратор и получить элементы при переборе в нужном порядке (так мы упорядочим сотрудников по наростанию зп).

Получив такую коллекцию мы можем посчитать среднюю зп для всех отделов, которые также положим в коллекцию типа ключ-значение, где ключ - имя отдела, значение - средняя зп, причем эта коллекция также сортирована по возростанию зп.

Дальше дело техники. Вы имеете две упорядоченные коллекции : имя отдела - список сотрудников в порядке возрастания зп и имя отдела - средняя зп в отделе по возрастанию. В комментариях вам подсказали алгоритм. У очереди есть удобные инструменты для получения с удалением и пр., чего нет в листе. Класса департамент больше нет, поэтому будет достаточно изменить его имя в самом классе работника и добавить в Map по ключу нового отдела.

Я использую lombok (которую вы также можете подключить) и класс Pair и спринга (он есть также в апачевских утилитах), но можете обойтись и без него.

Comment: По вашему коду не совсем хорошо ориентируюсь, плохо знаком со стримами. Могли бы по моему проконсультировать? В моём случае необходимо сейчас отсортировать MAP, в котором находится название отдела и департамент(информация о сотруднике)?

Comment: @Blacit вы понимаете, в чем проблема... вы сейчас спрашиваете примерно так: "забивать гвозди молотком я пока не умею, поэтому помогите мне забить гвоздь плоскогубцами". это, конечно, можно, только зачем? уже на этом этапе ваш код выглядит достаточно сложно и страшно. а вы только файл прочитали. формат данных, которые вы получили, уже на первом шаге вас не устраивает (сейчас полученный Map оказывается нужно сортировать). дальше будет хуже. в любом случае для сортировки нужно понимать параметры этой самой сортировки. по каким критериям вы хотите сортировать полученный Map?

Comment: Я пока что в целом не знаю, нужно ли вообще сортировать, либо можно уже произвести расчёты. Потому что всё необходимое есть, нужно среднюю заработную плату в отделах узнать, а следующим шагом является перевод сотрудников

Comment: @Blacit чтобы узнать среднюю зп по отделу, напишите метод в классе Department, в котором в цикле перебирайте все элементы коллекции сотрудников, суммируя в заранее объявленную переменную все зарплаты. а потом делим значение этой переменной на длинну коллекции. ну или сделайте как у меня .stream().mapToDouble(Employee::getSalary).average().getAsDouble()

Comment: Я вчера посидел, попробовал самостоятельно сделать, но не совсем удачно, могли бы подсказать, где должна находиться строка, которую предложили ввести со стримом. Не совсем понимаю, что нужно написать перед `.stream(). `Строка должна вот так выглядеть? `Map<String, Double> salaryAvg = .stream().mapToDouble(Employee::getSalary).average().getAsDouble();` Но то, что должно находится перед стримом - для меня загадка.

Comment: @Blacit все зависит от того, по какому пути вы идете. метод .stream() нужно вызвать у коллекции работников. в моем случае эта коллекция является значнием ранее полученной Map<String, Queue<Employee>> employes. У вас коллекция другая Map<String, Department> departments. Если вы идете по этому пути (у вас по прежнему есть класс Department), то добавьте в него метод     public double salaryAvg() { return employeeList.stream().mapToDouble(Employee::getSalary).average().getAsDouble(); }

Comment: Employee::getSalary подсвечивается красным, пишет, что Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert java.math.BigDecimal to double. Пошёл по второму пути, оставил департамент. Неверный тип возврата в ссылке на метод: невозможно преобразовать java.math.BigDecimal в double . Я использую BigDecimal , чтобы работать с числами, мне кажется, что это более корректно.

Comment: @Blacit вам не нужен BigDecimal в ваших классах. Измените его на обычный Double. Дело в том, что в реальной разработке деньги никто и никогда не считает в  BigDecimal  либо Double. Для этого есть Long.  Но в учебных целях можете пока использовать числа с плавающей точкой. Это и есть Double. А BigDecimal   нужен тогда, когда вам не хватает размера Double (и это явно не наш случай)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111356/discussion-between-blacit-and-).

Comment: Могли бы подсказать как всё же с BigDecimal это всё сделать, оказывается, что в задаче это просилось. Со стримами самостоятельно не удалось это произвести, как-то перебором надо, наверное.

Comment: @Blacit могу, но я сейчас понятия не имею, в чем у вас проблема. ваш исходный код уже поменялся. откорректируйте вопрос и предоставьте исходный код всех классов в актуальном состоянии

Comment: Отредактировал, всё готово

Comment: @Blacit если совсе не дружите со стримами и хотите BigDecimal, то для рассчета средней зп измените метод в классе Department : public BigDecimal salaryAvg() { BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;        
        for (Employee employee : employeeList) sum = sum.add(employee.getSalary()); return sum.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(employeeList.size())); }